# CSS Tableless layout

Tags: css, html

Help me to create this layout using Div/span

[image: Sample output / what i want]

the code i used and failed

```
<html>
<span>
  <span style="float:left">'.<img/> <br/> Text</span>
  <span style="float:right"> Long text <span>an inner span</span> </span>
  <br/>
  <div> a blank div</div>
</span>
</html>
```

*This code is cut paste from my PHP project*

it will be better if you avoid my faulty code and write a new one

Comment: you code is not readable, please consider only paste necessary code.

Comment: Unless you add display:block.  but there's no point

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple version that you can adjust as necessary.  It is just to get you started.

```
<img src="" id="logo">
<div id="topBar"></div>
<br class="clear" />
<div id="mainContent"></div>
<textarea></textarea>

img#logo{height:150px; width:20%; float:left; border:1px solid red;}
div#topBar{height:150px; width:78%; border:1px solid green; float:right;}
br.clear{clear:both;}
div#mainContent{height:150px; width:99%; border:1px solid blue; margin-top:10px;}
textarea{margin-top:10px; height:50px; width:99%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Y7K4D/

(You might also want to wrap this all in `wrapper div` and adjust the widths and margins for each element, fyi.)

Comment: Here's a small update i made of yours, got rid of the nasty floats and added the textfield: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7K4D/7/

Comment: Nicely done @Andreas Carlbom.  I didn't notice the `text` under the `img`.  +1

Comment: perhaps your layout matched exactly with the one in my Question but whenever i try to insert text in the div everything breaks, and it comes to a newline.

Comment: Hello Sourav, A vertical-align: top; on the affected div did the job. Here's an update for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7K4D/11/

Comment: Here's the another `text div` added to my original layout. http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Y7K4D/12/  You may need to adjust the heights on the `div`s for your own content.

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper {
                width: 100px;
            }
            #top-group {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            #wrapper img {
               float: left;
               height: 15px;
            }
            #wrapper #multiline {
               display: inline-block;
               white-space: normal;
            }
            #middle-group {
                clear:both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top-group">
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" alt="" />
            <div id="multiline">
                This is multiline div.
                This is multiline div.
                This is multiline div.
                This is multiline div.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle-group">
          This is middle div content
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-group">
           <textarea cols="5" rows="2">
           </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you missed the text just below of the image.